# .Net application settings

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I want to implement application settings to have them update settings that wont be set in a file i manage. I have the following so far:

In settings I have a variable named valuesforcomparison of type nameValueCollection and the scope is user. Now when I do the following the variable isnt updated the next time the user runs the program.

```
       public  void UpdatePropertySettings(NameValueCollection settings)
       {
        Properties.Settings.Default.valuesforcomparison = new NameValueCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.valuesforcomparison.Add(settings.GetKey(i), settings.GetValues(i)[0]);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();

        defVals = settings;

    }
```

Comment: try implementing it like the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565.aspx

Comment: I will look at that but I am also reading this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: After reading the above article by Lucas...the problem still persists. The actually implement it the same way as I have above. They just do it programmatically and I use the designer. They just bind the setting to a property. I dont want to do that.

Comment: I never would've figured out my problem with the ListItem type if not for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameValueCollection isnt supported.